# Firefox sort history based on time

Tags: firefox, history, sorting

Sadly it only seems possible to sort history on date

[image]
After collecting all sites of today (way too many) Firefox orders the history alphabetically. I want to sort only on time and date. Like with Chrome.

Comment: What's wrong with sorting "By Last Visited"?

Comment: @DavidPostill ah that's what I wanted... I didn't recognize that's what they meant with that wording. I'll accept if you change the comment into an answer.

Comment: Answer provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### I want to sort only on time and date

You can sort using "View" > "By Last Visited".

> The “last visited” option is similar to the default “by date” option except this too is just a long list with the most recent site visited first and then going back in time.

[image]

Note:

- I am using the "All-in-One Sidebar" and "Classic Theme Restorer" extensions" so the above screenshot may not accurately reflect your Firefox installation.

> Sadly it only seems possible to sort history on date

There are also other sorting options. See below.

---

#### Firefox History Function

> Every web page that you visit is logged by Firefox. This is what
>   constitutes your browsing history. If you click on the History text
>   link at the top of the browser you will open a drop-down list of your
>   most recent page visits. You can click on any of those links to return
>   to a page you have recently viewed.
>
> In the same drop-down is an option to “Show in Sidebar”. If you click
>   this link you will open a sidebar on the left of the browser window.
>   This sidebar will group your history for today, yesterday, two days
>   ago an so on. You can expand these groups to see all pages visited in
>   that time frame and then click on any page link to bring up that page
>   in the browser.
>
> By using the “View” button within the sidebar you can also sort and
>   group your History by date within site, site, most visited and last
>   visited.
>
> Sorting by “date and site” is better than “date” alone because it’s
>   easier to see which site you visited on a particular day. The default
>   “by date” option sorts alphabetically within day.
>
> Sorting “by site” is more useful if you just want to see all the pages
>   you have visited for a particular site regardless of when. Both these
>   options are sorted alphabetically by site. However, if you just sort
>   “by site” there is no grouping, just a single list. The “most visited”
>   sort option may give you an idea of which sites are your most popular,
>   but otherwise its usefulness is limited.
>
> The “last visited” option is similar to the default “by date” option except this too is just a long list with the most recent site visited first and then going back in time.

Source [Managing your browsing history in Firefox](http://www.digitalrise.biz/software/managing-your-browsing-history-in-firefox/)